# How to set up a wordpress website but still allow for development

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to set up a new website using wordpress but I am not sure which wordpress to download, I would like to be able to also write code for it, add pages if I need to. Does wordpress allows this?. (New to wordpress). What should I download in order to be able to set up the wordpress site and be able to modify code. Also, what will I need in terms of sql and server. Does apache work with it?.

I was reading on the WordPress site to just download the folder with 5 minute set up, is this what i would want?.

Comment: Do you have a local server like XAMPP, or MAMP?

Comment: I do not, What would be the best (not the easiest but the best), would tomcat or apache or something like that be better than XAMPP or MAMP?

Comment: XAMPP is usually fine and ive never had a problem with running wordpress on it. The only time you ever need to start messing about on the server side is when your website gets a lot of traffic and needs to start being smarter about bandwidth usage. See my answer below for the installation guide.

Comment: You should use Apache. Wordpress is a PHP powered platform. It won't work well on a Java server like tomcat. XAMPP is for windows, MAMP for Mac, they have everything you need to get going locally. Either one has an Apache server and a MySQL database which is required to run Wordpress.

Comment: Wordpress has many [tutorials](https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress_Locally_on_Your_Mac_With_MAMP) on how to get this set up.

Comment: How about modifying the code, i will have full access to it right?

Comment: Yes, that's the benefit of doing it locally. You can edit themes however you choose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its quite a simple process and should only take 5 minutes as it says.

You will need a server with MySQL and Apache capabilities.

For a quick tutorial/walkthrough which uses XAMPP for the Apache/MySQL, click [here](https://managewp.com/how-to-create-a-local-wordpress-website-in-windows-with-xampp)

Answer (score 0):

USE MAMP for this. I have done this and it works well. You can use heroku for deploy.